# How can I use Cypress to test a Snowpack app

Tags: javascript, cypress, snowpack

How can I use Cypress in a Snowpack + Svelte app? Snowpack only has docs for jest and `@web/test-runner`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cypress the same way as you used it with Webpack config. By default, Cypress uses webpack to run test scripts. Simply install cypress and you're ready to go (visit: [Cypress Preprocessors](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/plugins-guide#Preprocessors)). If you'd like your test to be bundled with Snowpack- there is no current solution for this. All other options are listed here: [list of preprocessor plugins](https://docs.cypress.io/plugins/directory). The cypress developers right now are overwhelmed and can't develop a snowpack plugin by themselves, but they are open to suggestions (PRs). To watch for any updates visit this issue: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/14285